# How write django views based on sparql results from an ontolgy?

Tags: django, django-views, sparql, owl, ontology

I have built a Django web application that takes in a textual description of a system. I then used natural language processing to extract specific textual information. The extracted information is then populated (as individuals) into an ontology (.owl) using a Owlready2. Once the ontology is populated, I can run SPARQL queries. Now, I would like to display the query results in a template via class base view.

Currently, I dont know where to start with a solution. I can only think of converting the query results to json and the put it in the class based view.

Below is some code to get the SPARQL results.

```py
from owlready2 import *
import owlready2
owlready2.JAVA_EXE = "mypath"


world = World()

world.get_ontology("file://C:\\mypath\\RDFContext_Test.owl").load()
sync_reasoner(world)
print(world)

graph = world.as_rdflib_graph()


r = graph.query("""
    PREFIX UC: <http://www.semanticweb.org/name/ontologies/2018/8/untitled-ontology-2#>
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    prefix xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
    select ?use_case ?flgroup where {
    ?use_case UC:hasGoal "V" .
    ?use_case UC:hasFlowGroup ?flgroup.
    ?flgroup a UC:SpecificAltFlowGroup .}""")
```

However, I dont know where to go from here to display it in the template. Can some point me in the right direction?

Comment: Django is an opinionated framework and in its opinion you should be using RDBS for your models. Due to the lack of support I gave up on Django for Semantic Web years ago and switched to an unopinionated framework (Flask). However, since then, `django-rdf-io` has been authored, which looks quite promising.

Comment: I will check it out. Thanks. Currently, I am using a work around.